# BCNF (3.5NF) Decomposition Issues

Tags: database, database-schema, database-normalization, bcnf

I have a relation:

```
R(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q)
```

which I am trying to decompose into BCNF, here are my Functional Dependencies:

```
 - A -> B, C, D
 - B -> A, C, D
 - C -> A, B, D
 - D -> A, B, C
 - F -> A, B, C, D, E, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q
 - A, E, G -> B, C, D, F, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q
```

Although C is the clear choice for primary key, it is a field that is about a paragraph long so I have chose A, E, G as a composite key instead because placing queries would be too messy.

I appreciate that there are many questions similar to this on this site as well as on other sources on the web but I just can't seem to replicate their solutions in my own problem.

Thanks for your time,

Comment: Can anyone give me some advice? I can't carry on with my project until I have decomposed my relation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This relation has five (candidate) keys:

```
{ (A, E, G) (B, E, G) (C, E, G) (D, E, G) (F) }
```

The decomposition in BCNF, using the analysis algorithm, produces the following two relations:

```
R1 (A, B, C, D)
R2 (A, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q)
```

Comment: Thanks you're a star